# Linux + why dropping issue displayed from ifconfig but not from ethtool?

Tags: networking, redhat-enterprise-linux, esxi, ifconfig

we have Linux VM red hat 7.2 version with two LAN interfaces

the Linux machines are ruining on ESXi - 5.5.0

and we have very strange issue ,

the conflict is between the ifconfig command to ethtool command results!

why the results from ethtool isn't indicates on dropping problem on eth1

while from ifconfig I get the indicates that dropping problem exist on eth1?

( see ifconfig - increasing of numbers on dropped indicates on dropping error )

```
   # ethtool -S eth1 | grep -i drop
   drv dropped tx total: 0
   drv dropped tx total: 0
   drv dropped rx total: 0
   drv dropped rx total: 0
```

ifconfig results on eth1:

```
    # ifconfig -a | grep RX | grep dropped
    RX errors 0  dropped 123136  overruns 0  frame 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 140938047  overruns 0  frame 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0

    # ifconfig -a | grep RX | grep dropped
    RX errors 0  dropped 123136  overruns 0  frame 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 140938083  overruns 0  frame 0  <--------------  after second
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
```

second - is it true to except the results from ethtool as real results 
while the results from ifconfig actually inst indicate on problem?

remark - drooping problem are only displayed on Linux version 7.x and not on the other Linux version as 6.x or 5.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ethtool` command breaks up the RX (received) drops into different categories, but lumps the TX (transmitted) drops into a single group. For example, running `ifconfig` shows:

```
# ifconfig eth0 | grep dropped
          RX packets:169700121 errors:0 dropped:2811 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:173242722 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
```

But if I now run `ethtool` and look for just the RX errors, I see:

```
# ethtool -S eth0 | egrep rx_.*_errors                                                                                                                                                                  
     rx_length_errors: 0
     rx_over_errors: 0
     rx_crc_errors: 0
     rx_frame_errors: 0
     rx_missed_errors: 2811
     rx_long_length_errors: 0
     rx_short_length_errors: 0
     rx_align_errors: 0
     rx_csum_offload_errors: 203
```

Now you can see that 2811 packets were dropped due to the `rx_missed_errors`.